# Creating multiple IAM groups with multiple IAM policies using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am trying to create multiple IAM Groups and then attach multiple AWS policies to each group using terraform (v0.12).

Currently I have:

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "group1" {
  name = "group1"
  path = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "group2" {
  name = "group2"
  path = "/"
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "group1" {
  for_each = toset([
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCodeGuruProfilerFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/job-function/Billing"
  ])
  group      = aws_iam_group.group1.name
  policy_arn = each.value
}
```

Is there a cleaner way for this to be done so that I won't end up using so much duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [`setproduct`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html) function to achieve this functionality.

For example, given the following Terraform configuration:

```
variable "group_names" {
  default = []
  type    = set(string)
}

variable "policy_arns" {
  default = []
  type    = set(string)
}

locals {
  group_policies = [
    for group_policy in setproduct(var.group_names, var.policy_arns) : {
      group_name = group_policy[0]
      policy_arn = group_policy[1]
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "iam_group" {
  for_each = var.group_names

  name = each.value
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
  for_each = {
    for group_policy in local.group_policies : "${group_policy.group_name}.${group_policy.policy_arn}" => group_policy
  }

  group      = each.value.group_name
  policy_arn = each.value.policy_arn
}
```

Results in the following plan:

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_group.iam_group["group1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group" "iam_group" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "group1"
      + path      = "/"
      + unique_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_iam_group.iam_group["group2"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group" "iam_group" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "group2"
      + path      = "/"
      + unique_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group1.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCodeGuruProfilerFullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group1"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCodeGuruProfilerFullAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group1.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group1"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group1.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group1"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group2.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCodeGuruProfilerFullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group2"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCodeGuruProfilerFullAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group2.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group2"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess"
    }

  # aws_iam_group_policy_attachment.iam_group_policy_attachment["group2.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "iam_group_policy_attachment" {
      + group      = "group2"
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
    }

Plan: 8 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

The `setproduct` function returns all the possible combinations of elements given 2 or more arguments.

The `for_each` expression in the `aws_iam_group_policy_attachment` creates a map of key-value pairs where each key is formatted like so `group_name.policy_arn` (e.g., `"group2.arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"`) and each value is a map containing two keys, `group_name` and `policy_arn`, respectively.

It is important to create a unique key in the `for_each` expression to prevent the possibility of overwriting existing keys in the map.